# java: constructor ranngeIpScanner in class cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java

Im new in java i have this Class :

```
public class ranngeIpScanner
{
    public static void main(String IpAddress)
    {
        String IpAddress = IpAddress;
        String[] octets = IpAddress.split("\\.");
        System.out.println(octets);
        //some more work here ...
    }


}
```

and i instantiated it in another class like this :

```
ranngeIpScanner scanIp = new ranngeIpScanner("192.198.1.200");
```

when i try to compile it i get the following error

```
Error:(45, 42) java: constructor ranngeIpScanner in class com.server.scanner.ranngeIpScanner cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

forgive me if my question is a little noob i didnt know what to search for

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, the `main` method is different from the constructor for a class.

Your code above declares the `main` method, but does not define a constructor. As a result, Java implicitly creates the default constructor:

```
public ranngeIpScanner() { super(); }
```

Note that this default constructor has no parameters.

When you write the line...

```
ranngeIpScanner scanIp = new ranngeIpScanner("192.198.1.200");
```

...you are calling the **constructor**, *not* the `main` method. Thus, Java complains that you are attempting to give a `String` to `ranngeIpScanner`'s constructor, which by default takes no arguments.

The fix for this is easy: Instead of

```
public static void main(String ipAddress)
```

you should write

```
public ranngeIpScanner(String ipAddress)
```

This changes the `main` method to a constructor for your class.

Also, a little tip: Java convention is to start class names with capital letters and variable names with lowercase ones. Your class `ranngeIpScanner` is better named `RangeIpScanner`, and the variable `IpAddress` should be called `ipAddress`.